# getting ini information from perl

Tags: perl, ini

I was wondering how to retrieve information from an INI file in perl. I found something at the perl.org documentation
[here](http://learn.perl.org/examples/configuration_files.html), however it is not commented, and would need some explaining. Are there any easier to use modules for parsing the INI information??

```
[version]
ver=1.0.3

[ServerInfo]
port=1234
address="localhost"
```

Comment: What's the question? What information do you want?

Comment: I want to know how to retrieve the info from the ini in perl and then print the info on the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good [INI file reader in CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Config-INI-0.018/lib/Config/INI/Reader.pm), which you can sublclass if you want.

```
% cpan install 'Config::INI::Reader'
```

Then...

```
% cat blah.pl 
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w

use strict;
use Config::INI::Reader;

my $filename = "blah.ini";

my $ini = Config::INI::Reader->read_file($filename);
my $server_info = $ini->{'ServerInfo'};

printf "Will connect to %s:%d\n"
    , $server_info->{'address'}
    , $server_info->{'port'}
    ;
```

Running:

```
% ./blah.pl 
Will connect to "localhost":1234
```

You don't need the `"` in your INI file.

Comment: thanks when I first starting researching ini's I read them in c++ when I saw the example ini it had the "

Comment: You shouldn't need the quotation marks in the INI file regardless of the langage implementing the reader.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this by example :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::IniFiles;

my $ini = new Config::IniFiles(
    -file => '/tmp/config.ini',
    -allowcontinue => 1
);

print $ini->val('version', 'ver');
```

See `perldoc Config::IniFiles`

Answer (score 0):

When working out how to do something in Perl, your first step should always be to search [CPAN](http://metacpan.org/) for useful-looking modules.

In this case, [searching for "ini"](https://metacpan.org/search?q=ini) gives you plenty of options to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the [Config::Auto](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config%3a%3aAuto) module.